# Flexible array size in C

Tags: c

I am coding an MCMC algorithm in C and I have a little problem. The idea of this algorithms is to make inferences for the number of groups in a population. So let us say that we start with k groups. Where the first value for k is given by the user or randomly selected. Now at each step of the algorithm k can decrease by 1, increase by 1 or stay the same. And I have some variables for each group;

```
double *mu;
double *lambda;
double **A
```

mu and lambda are indeed arrays of k elements and A is a two dimensional array of kxN. N as well changes at each iteration. I have some data y1, y2,..., yn so at each iteration I do some process, propose new values for the parameters and decide if to move k or not.

So far I have tied to use malloc and realloc to deal with all this changes of the dimension of my parameters but I have to iterate this algorithm for let us say 100,000 times so at certain point it crashes. If I start with k=10 in my case at the third iteration!

So two questions:

- Can I use realloc at each iteration? or this is my big mistake. If yes well I imagine that should check my code!
- If not what should I do, any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using std::vector or other dynamic containers that do most of the memory management for you.

Comment: If I were you I'd use a higher level language that took care of memory allocation for you.  MCMC is hard enough to get right at the best of times, but if you are grubbing around with `malloc` it's a long road.

Comment: Have you considered using Linked lists instead?

Answer (score 4):

I would consider *not* changing your storage on every iteration.  `realloc` carries considerable overhead (in the worst-case, it has to copy your entire array every single time).

Can you simply allocate for the maximum dimensions at startup, and then just use less of it?  Or at the very least, only `realloc` on an *increase* in storage requirements by doubling your capacity (thus mimicking how a `std::vector` operates).

*[By the way, I don't know why your application crashes, as you haven't given us any details (e.g. the error message you get, or what you've found by debugging.  But I guess you have a bug somewhere!]*

Comment: The range of k is from 1 to 30 so maybe I should just define the variables that depend on k as arrays of 30 entries and just use the necessary ones. I do not like this but I think I have no better options. I already have the code in R but it is very slow, that is why I am trying with C, maybe I should have learned FORTRAN or C++